# Total sum of html table column values(dynamic)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax

I want the sum of total column whenever the value of any cell in total column gets changed.
what actually is I am doing that when i click on any '**add**' button it gets hide and other '**remove**' button gets displayed and corresponding input also gets enabled and If I put some value in input then it updates the value in the next cell which is in '**Total**' column and sum of this '**Total**' column I want whenever value of any cell in this column gets changed then it updates the '**sum**'.

```js
function updatevalue(item, value, data) {
  var td = item.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  var onupdate = 0;
  if (value) {
    onupdate = data * value;
  } else if (value === 0) {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  } else {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  }
  td.innerHTML = onupdate;
}

function add_item(item, next) {
  item.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  next.style.display = "block";
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.value = '';
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.disabled = false;
}

function remove_item(item, prev) {
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.disabled = true;
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.value = '0';
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = '0';
  item.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  prev.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>Select</th>
  <th>Intake</th>
  <th>Total</th>
  {% for a in top_energy %}
  <tr>
    <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
    <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
    <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
    <td>0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
    <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
    <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
    <td onkeyup="totalval(this)">0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
    <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
    <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
    <td onkeyup="totalval(this)">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>I want the sum of total column whenever the value of any cell in total column gets changed</td>
    <td></td>
    <td>sum</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. You need to have your `<th>` inside a `<tr>` which should ideally be inside a `<thead>`. All text nodes inside a `<table>` should be inside a `<tr>` or a `<th>`. There's a lot of duplicated code as well, you should be using `addEventListener` instead of `onclick` attributes.

Comment: Also multiple duplicated IDs.  IDs must be unique.   Doesn't seem to cause an issue here though as not attempting to use the IDs

Comment: Exactly which part are you having difficulty with?  Calling a function from inside `add_item`/`remove_item`?   Looping through `tr`?  Finding the correct column/cell?  (seem to have this covered even if it is an ugly .next.next.next.next).  Adding values together?  There's doesn't seem to a problem described here, only a requirement, which isn't what SO is for.  (subtle different between "I want" and "how can I")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, I added "int-input" class to  that had value in it
and afther that I selected all of them

```
var totalValues = document.querySelectorAll(".int-input");
var total = 0;
totalValues.forEach((k) => {
  total += parseInt(k.innerHTML);
});
```

and then I add number to result

```js
function updatevalue(item, value, data) {
  var td = item.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
  var onupdate = 0;
  if (value) {
    onupdate = data * value;
  } else if (value === 0) {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  } else {
    onupdate = data * 0;
  }
  td.innerHTML = onupdate;
  var totalValues = document.querySelectorAll(".int-input");
  var total = 0;
  totalValues.forEach((k) => {
    total += parseInt(k.innerHTML);
  });
  document.querySelector(".total").innerHTML = total;
}

function add_item(item, next) {
  item.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  next.style.display = "block";
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.value = '';
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.disabled = false;
}

function remove_item(item, prev) {
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.disabled = true;
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.firstChild.value = '0';
  item.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = '0';
  item.parentNode.style.display = "none";
  prev.style.display = "block";
}
```

```html
<table>
  <th>Select</th>
  <th>Intake</th>
  <th>Total</th>
  {% for a in top_energy %}
  <tr>
    <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
    <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
    <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
    <td class="int-input">0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
    <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
    <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
    <td class="int-input" onkeyup="totalval(this)">0</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td><input id="btn" type="button" value="Add" name="{{a.Food}}" onclick="add_item(this, this.parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling)"></td>
    <td style="display: none;text-align: center;"><input id="btn" type="button" name="{{a.Food}}" value="Remove" onclick="remove_item(this,this.parentNode.previousElementSibling)"></td>
    <td><input type="Number" name="some" id="{{a.Food}}" value="0" oninput="updatevalue(this,this.value,9)" disabled></td>
    <td class="int-input" onkeyup="totalval(this)">0</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>I want the sum of total column whenever the value of any cell in total column gets changed</td>
    <td class="total">0</td>
    <td>sum</td>
  </tr>
  {% endfor %}

</table>
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Comment: i have solved the diferent div problem thnx for your help but if you can help plz tell me how to resolve remove problem because on remove function the value of sum is not updating . thnk you again

Comment: plz check this function is that right way to do this

Comment: `  function updatevalue(item, value, data) {
   var td = item.parentNode.nextElementSibling;
   var div = item.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode;
   var onupdate = 0;
   if (value) {
     onupdate = data * value;
   } else if (value === 0) {
     onupdate = data * 0;
   } else {
     onupdate = data * 0;
   }
   td.innerHTML = onupdate;
   var totalValues = div.querySelectorAll(".int-input");
   var total = 0;
   totalValues.forEach((k) => {
     total += parseInt(k.innerHTML);
   });
   div.querySelector('.total').innerHTML = total
}`

Comment: sorry for this code format because I dont know how to right code in comment